# looking for help setting up stepper motor code blocks in klipper printer.cfg file

Tags: klipper, tronxy

the machine in question is a tronxy veho 600. i have obtained a printer.cfg file for a highly modified veho 600 but my one is standard bar the cr touch i have yet to install.

the reason for this post is to understand why some of the setting in the modified printer.cfg are the way they are. following is the code for the 3 stepper motors

```
[stepper_x]
step_pin: PE5
dir_pin: !PF1
enable_pin: !PF0
microsteps: 16
rotation_distance: 60
endstop_pin: !PC15
position_endstop: -5
position_min: -5
position_max: 600 # for bed mesh
homing_speed: 200
homing_retract_dist: 10
second_homing_speed: 10.0

[stepper_y]
step_pin: PF9
dir_pin:  PF3
enable_pin: !PF5
microsteps: 16
rotation_distance: 60
endstop_pin: !PC14
position_endstop: -10
position_min: -10
position_max: 600
homing_retract_dist: 10
homing_speed: 100.0
second_homing_speed: 10.0

[stepper_z]
step_pin: PF6
dir_pin: !PF4
enable_pin: !PF7
microsteps: 16
rotation_distance: 12
endstop_pin: probe:z_virtual_endstop
endstop_pin: !PF11
#position_endstop: 611
position_max: 620
position_min: -5
homing_speed: 25.0
homing_retract_dist: 10
second_homing_speed: 10.0

[stepper_z1]
step_pin: PA6
dir_pin: !PF15
enable_pin: !PA5
microsteps: 16
rotation_distance: 12
endstop_pin: !PC13
#position_endstop: 600
```

for the x and y axis.....

1. step pin, according to klipper config reference it says "triggered high" what does this mean? i thought this was just a pin id.
2. dir_pin, stated as not pf1. again i thought this is just a pin id so why the !, what am i missing?
3. same as question 2 only for the enable pin.
4. endstop_pin again set to not pc15.
5. position_endstop set to -5. is this something i need to measure when the machine is running?
6. position_min, same as question 5
7. position_max, obviously this is just the size of the bed and i would have left the thought train there but but the original creator states in a comment that it is for bed mesh which peaques my curiosity.

8.homing speed, is this just the speed the machine homes to once a print is finished or the homing function is initiated?

9. homing_retract_dist. my guess is that when the homing function is initiated it moves to the corner of the bed, then moves another 10mm to bring it off the bed. is that correct?
10. second_homing_speed set to 10 here, why does it have two homing speeds and why are there such large distances?

for the z axis.....

1. most of the questions i have already asked im only wondering why there are endstop properties and then measurements for "position_max and position_min". shouldnt the end stop switches pick up this automatically? and also in z1 stepper why is position_endstop commented out?

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a dozen questions in one post. Please check [help](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help) section and improve your posts. Personally, I'd create separate posts for these questions you can't find any answers to elsewhere.

Comment: thanks for your input, however i can only post one question every 40 mins, i have about 25 questions to post in total, so sorry if this is an inconvenience to you but i have a very limited amount of time

Comment: @Generalraid what kosteklvp is saying is not that it is an inconvenience but more about how the site works. I recommend you take the [Tour] and visit the Help Center's section on [Asking](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/asking) questions. In short, if one user answers part of your questions and another user answers the other parts, as the asker you can only select **one** of the answers as correct.